# Quasar CLI with Vite + Django | Quasar SPA - Django

Tags: django, single-page-application, vite, quasar-framework, quasar

## How to integrate Quasar SPA app with Django?

#### Using:

***Quasar CLI with Vite***

***Django***

Expected to have Django serving *'Index.html'* and other static files build by *'quasar build'* command.

Which resides in *"application/dist"* and *"application/dist/assets"* directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This is an answer for those who comes here looking for a solution.

================================================================

### This one specific to Django serving 'Index.html' and static files of your Quasar app.

---

#### In order to integrate your Quasar SPA app you need to configure your *'quasar.config.js'* as following.

```
build: {
  publicPath: "/<your-django-app>", // <-- e.g. https://your-domain.com/django-app/dist-dir
  distDir: "dist", // <-- depends on your setup, you can leave it to 
                   //     default, but then you have to configure your 
                   //     paths below according to this path.

  extendViteConf(viteConf) {
    viteConf.base = "/static/your-django-app/dist/";
    viteConf.build.polyfillModulePreload = true; // <-- suggested by *https://v2.vitejs.dev/config/#build-polyfillmodulepreload*
    viteConf.build.outDir = "dist"; //<-- default value
    viteConf.build.assetsDir = "assets"; // <-- default value
  }
}
```

#### Django static files setup *'settings.py'*

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join("static"),
    os.path.join("static/<your-django-app>/dist/assets"),
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help.
I try set it, however without any success.
Seems almost all your commands are pretty unsure, what they mean.
Examples:
 - publicPath should be a string or an url?
 - You assign some string to viteConf.base. This gives me an error "The
   value can only be an absolute URL, ./, or an empty string."
 - when I generate SPA then the output is usually to dist/spa directory; I am not sure if /spa should be mentioned somewhere,
 - ...

Comment: @mirek sorry for your issues bro, you can check in your 'quasar.config.js' under the key build.distDir: "dist", this has to change build directory.
For the public path, is exactly as it's mentioned above, read carefully. It's path after your domain. Where you want those files from build ('dist' directory) to be served. So, 'https://example.com/your-app' if you have extra app in your django and your spa is meant to be applied there, you write this '/your-app'. but, if your app is being served from django in 'https://example.com', in this case you leave 'publicPath' with default  '/'.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the command, I am not able to implement the "accepted answer".
So at this time I have just one solution, based on [pythonanywhere.com hosting docs](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/React/).

I have backend/ (ie.django) and frontend/ (ie.quasar) folders inside the project root, I do `quasar build` with just one change, in `quasar.config.js` section `build`: `publicPath: '/static'`,

So build output is in `frontend/dist/spa`.

In django settings I made the things based on pythonanywhere article:

```
_FRONTEND_DIR = BASE_DIR.parent / "frontend"
_FRONTEND_BUILD_DIR = _FRONTEND_DIR / "dist" / "spa"
TEMPLATES[0]["DIRS"].append(_FRONTEND_BUILD_DIR)
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  _FRONTEND_BUILD_DIR,
  _FRONTEND_BUILD_DIR / "assets",
]
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "static/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media/"
```

In `urls.py`, `urlpatterns` I have additional line:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
path("", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
```

Seems it works, together with django `admin`. But I have no idea how fast, efficient, secure,.. it is.